# Material Alpha Blend: Blending issue

Tags: materials, transparency

Hello Guys This is my first model and having hard time to follow tutorial that was made on older versions of the Blender.

Now I use 2.9 version which shows some weird behavior couldn't find the answer. please check the gif below to see it. when I switch to Alpha Hashed blending fixes but feathers appear pixelated or what. please any advice would be much appreciated.

One guy suggested to use same materials but in that case I will not have multi colored feathers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there faces directly overlapping each other? That often causes problems. And: have you set the Blend Mode to Alpha Hashed on each feather material or just the one that seems to cause problems? Try setting them all to Alpha Hashed, maybe set the Shadow Mode to Alpha Hashed as well. Apart from that, my experience with Eevee is that it's sometimes not showing correctly in the viewport expecially when the view changes quickly until you stop the movement - so the issue should not appear when you render it as animation.

Comment: thank you, but...
- meshes do not overlap it is not z fighting
- if I set to Alpha Hashed issue is fixed, but I get edge of the feathers pixelated, noisy.
- rendered image also shows the issue.

Comment: The rendered image would be interesting to look at, maybe also the blend file to further investigate this issue. As I said, my experience is that the 3D viewport in Eevee is always a bit different and messy from the real render. For clarification: you have Alpha Hashed on both Blend Mode and Shadow Mode, on all feather materials?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for getting back, with Alpha Hashed issue disappears but the feather look noisy, I want to go with Alpha blend, the shadows are Opaque, even when I turn of shadows issue stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed when I combined all feather meshes into one mesh.